# How to change the ORDER ID generator in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to increment the order number (POST number) by a random number, such as 1 through 50? Instead of incrementing 1 by 1?

Where is this operation located?
Thanks!

Comment: The order number is the post ID, so you can't do it for the post ID… Now woocommerce has an "order number" that can be different from the post ID.  You can have a look to the code of the free plugin [Sequential Order Numbers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/) where you might be able to make what you expect…

Comment: Is this feature only available starting on the wordpress 5.0 version? Thanks!

Comment: Please think a little bit, Wordpress has nothing to do with that… it's about and related to Woocommerce Orders and Order number (see `WC_Order` `get_order_number()` method and `woocommerce_order_number` related filter hook).